# Android Studio Emulator, cannot find certificate

Tags: эмулятор, avd

Установил android studio 3.6, пытаюсь запустить эмулятор андроид, но при запуске он бесконечно загружается и вылезает варнинг: Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\Nik.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled. В инете толком нет информации по данной проблеме

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте таким образом, я просто случайно "натыкал" решение.